# Rails multiple database sessions, any drawbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, database

I have and app where I'm providing predictive input for postal codes of several countries.
As you can imagine there's plenty of data that needs to be stored to do that.

I'm using different databases to store the data of several countries. As I support more countries the number of DBs will grow. I'm storing them in mongodb via mongoid.

This is how I do it:

```
class France_codes
    include Mongoid::Document
    store_in session: "db_south_europe"
end
```

That session is defined in mongoid.yml

```
production:
    sessions:
        default:
            uri: "mongodb://...."

        db_south_europe:
            uri: "mongodb://...."

        db_north_europe:
            uri: "mongodb://...."
```

To select one of the connections.
I get the country name and make it a constant so I can use its methods.

```
p = (country+"_codes").constantize
results = p.where(:cp => /^#{prefix}/).pluck(:pl)
```

I haven't see any issues with it so far. But I am about to add another DB to the system. I have 7 right now...

The question is:

Is it bad to have several DB sessions ready for use set up this way? Or is this acceptable?
Mainly thinking about memory footprint, performance, etc. 
These databases are externally hosted, I'm so far running it at Heroku. We are talking about reads from the DB in this case, nothing is ever written to those DBs from the application. Though I have some other DBs which are used to store data and setup in the same way.

Thanks.

Comment: one question: for what do you need so many DBs?

Comment: One example: the UK has 1.8 million postal codes. At this point I use free hosting for my mongodb DBs. The free size limit is 500MB. The UK documents alone almost reach the free DB limit. I would need a much bigger DB to have all EU postal codes in a single DB. And I don't know if then search would be slower. So the answer is the space that each country needs for the documents, though some are fairly small and share the same DB.

Comment: Hmm. It is not a question of DB selection. Free hosting for Postgresql also has storage limitation and I would probably end in the same situation. I'm quite satisfied with Mongodb. If I would change DBs for this I would go for Redis, but that's quite expensive for big DBs.

Comment: Yeah well... sorry. Right Redis is not a DB. I know Redis is not a DB, I shouldn't have called Redis a DB. Thanks for your comments but the topic of the discussion has moved to a DB selection issue (or in-memory key-value-pair storage). The original post is NOT about what DB or storage mechanism to use.

Comment: Since the question is `Rails multiple databases, any drawbacks?`, so that topic is about DB mechs. And the main drawback is that mant DBs require increased cost to support then against the single.

Comment: Now the title of the question is not about databases.